# What is the difference between a constructor reference and a lambda expression that invokes a constructor?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm studying Stream APIs in Java 8 and I'm facing a problem. The problem is I'm trying to understand the differences between `()->new StringBuilder` and  `StringBuilder::new`  in the following code:

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(new String[]{"b", "a", "s", "i", "l",});
StringBuilder basil = stream.collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append);
System.out.println("basil");
```

and

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(new String[]{"b", "a", "s", "i", "l",});
    StringBuilder basil = stream.collect(()->new StringBuilder(), StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append);
    System.out.println("basil");
```

When should I use the first syntax, and when should I choose the second one?

And why the above code accept `StringBuilder::append` and doesn't accept `StringBuilder::reverse`

Comment: They are functionally equivalent. The second is called a ['method reference'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: Both is equivalent. I would recommend using the method references if possible, since its more compact and in my opinion more readable. It's opinion based.

Comment: @Zabuza It's not always more compact. A private static method is often more verbose when written as a method reference.

Comment: Yeah, go for whatever you find more readable and appropriate in a specific situation.

Comment: it's mainly "the same" thing, if you *really* care, the method reference will create one less synthetic method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lambda expression (`()->new StringBuilder()`) and the method reference (`StringBuilder::new`) you are asking about are equivalent. Use whichever looks more readable to you.

As for the second question:

Consider the signature of `collect`:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

The second argument is a `BiConsumer` whose first parameter is the type of the output of the `collect` operation and whose second parameter is the type of the `Stream` element. In your case you need a `BiConsumer<StringBuilder,String>`. `StringBuilder append(String str)` matches this functional interface, since it has a `StringBuilder` input (the instance on which it is called) and a `String` input.

`StringBuilder reverse()` doesn't match this functional interface, since it only has a `StringBuilder` input and no `String` input.

Comment: How i can  pass some variable to to a method reference ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Before asking follow up questions, please actually [do some research yourself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: @Eran Thank you for answering me.  i did i got confused a bit and i didn't know how could i search about them

Comment: @Eran Yes actually it was before your ansawer Sorry about that

Comment: @Eran i rollback the question as the orginal thank you for your help